# Critical angle of photon emission for a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

For a Schwarzschild black hole of mass $M$, we know that for a stationary observer at Schwarzschild  coordinate $r$, the maximum angle from the radially outward direction that a photon can be emitted by the observer without the photon falling into the black hole is,

$$\psi=\arcsin \left(\frac{\sqrt{27}GM}{r}\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r}}\right)$$

Does this relation hold even for radially free falling observers? For simplicity let us assume this observer started falling from rest at infinity. I am unable to prove or disprove whether the same relation will hold for the maximum angle of photon emission. Can someone help me with this? If the same relation does not hold then what is the new relation?